# How to (dis)prove Mahalanobis $ d^2 $ is non decreasing?

Tags: self-study, multivariate-analysis, mahalanobis

I have been studying multivariate analysis and hypothesis testing , and came across this question in back exercise

> Define Mahalabonis measure of distance squared between
> two populations with a common positive definite dispersion matrix and show
> that it is a non decreasing function of the number of characteristics.

I searched this on Google,  and read that mahalanobis $ d^2 $ indicates the correlation , and since correlation increases as the number of characteristics increase,  so can we write this as the explanation to the question?

I am confused about how to properly prove this thing on paper .

Comment: Without more context and explanation this question is indecipherable.  What are "characteristics" (variables perhaps?) and in what way does their number increase?  What is "Mahalanobis $d^2$"--would it be the Mahalanobis distance?  If so, between what and what, based on what distribution??

Comment: @whuber I have added the complete question of the back exercise, kindly help if you know ..

Comment: Thank you.  This is *not* what is usually meant by "Mahalanobis distance" and it is not a measure of correlation (unless perhaps the "populations" have been pre-processed by centering each of them separately).  One way to interpret the question that makes it correct is to suppose that "characteristics" are components of $n$-vectors and that the "common pd dispersion matrix" is an $n\times n$ matrix where you contemplate what happens when you zero out its last row and column (to eliminate a "characteristic").

Comment: If I would zero out its last row , then its rank changes (decreases ) , also determinant might change , but how to put this on paper , I would have a 15 marker question on this , I dont think this theory would be that effective

Comment: The result is a direct consequence of the positive-semidefinite property of the matrix.

Comment: I suggest closing this question because it is explicitly mentioned in the bounty that it is an "exam" question.  No answer should be given for it would be unfair for other students who took the same exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to define a Mahalanobis distance for two points (your populations?), $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ is

$$d(\vec{x},\vec{y},D) = \sqrt{(\vec{x}-\vec{y})^T D (\vec{x}-\vec{y})}$$

with $D$ the dispersion matrix.

With a characteristic less this could mean that one of the indices is zero. If it is like that then the Mahalanobis distance is not necessarily a non-decreasing function of the number of characteristics.

#### Counterexample

Take for instance the following case with two features/characteristics

$$D, = \begin{bmatrix}1&-0.9\\-0.9&1\end{bmatrix} \qquad \vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} \qquad \vec{y} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

then $$d(\vec{x},\vec{y},D) = \sqrt{0.2}$$

But with one characteristic less

$$D, = \begin{bmatrix}1&-0.9\\-0.9&1\end{bmatrix} \qquad \vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} \qquad \vec{y} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

then we have a *larger* distance $$d(\vec{x},\vec{y},D) = \sqrt{1}$$